# How to checkout the contents of a directory in git?

Tags: git, deployment, git-checkout

I have a repo with a 'htdocs` directory in its root, is it possible to checkout only the contents of this folder? I tried running:

```
git checkout -f master -- htdocs
```

Which does ignore everything else in the repo root but it also brings in the `htdocs` folder. I could copy the contents and remove the directory with a couple additional commands but I was wondering if it was possible with through git only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout in an external folder, and make a symbolic link between /htdocs and that folder.